# how can i select and kill multiple application

Tags: java, android

I'm a newbie in android and my thesis is just like the "Battery Doctor Saver" in android. My number 1 problem is to select multiple application and kill it at once. Honestly I already have my no.1 problem but my problem is I can only kill one application at a time. So here is my code thank you for your immediate response to my question :).

```
package plm.thesis.taskkiller;


public class TaskKillerActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "TaskKillerActivity";
    TaskListAdapter adapter;
    RefreshReceiver receiver;

    class RefreshReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static final String TAG = "RefreshReceiver";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "refreshing");
            clearRunningProcessesList();
            loadRunningProcesses();

        }

    }

    public void clearRunningProcessesList() {
        adapter.clearTasks();
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        adapter = new TaskListAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        loadRunningProcesses();
        receiver = new RefreshReceiver();
        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver,
                new IntentFilter("plm.thesis.taskkiller.REFRESH_RECEIVER"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    public void loadRunningProcesses() {

        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appinfolist = activityManager
                .getRunningAppProcesses();

        Log.d(TAG, "AppInfoList Size: " + appinfolist.size());

        for (RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : appinfolist) {
            TaskObject runningtask = new TaskObject();
            runningtask.pid = runningAppProcessInfo.pid;
            runningtask.processName = runningAppProcessInfo.processName;
            adapter.addTask(runningtask);
        }
    }

    class TaskObject {
        int pid;
        String processName;
    }

    class TaskListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static final String TAG = "TaskListAdapter";

        ArrayList<TaskKillerActivity.TaskObject> list;
        Context context;

        public TaskListAdapter(Context context) {
            Log.d(TAG, "created new task list adapter");
            this.context = context;
            if (list == null) {
                list = new ArrayList<TaskKillerActivity.TaskObject>();
            }
        }

        public void addTask(TaskObject taskObject) {
            list.add(taskObject);
        }

        public void clearTasks() {
            list.clear();
            Log.d(TAG, "list size:" + list.size());
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public TaskObject getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taskitem, null);
            TextView textPid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.taskPid);
            textPid.setText(Integer.toString(getItem(position).pid));
            TextView textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.taskName);
            textName.setText(getItem(position).processName);
            Button buttonKill = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.taskKill);
            buttonKill.setTag(getItem(position).processName);
            CheckBox chckKill = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.appSelected);
            chckKill.setTag(getItem(position).pid);

            view.findViewById(R.id.taskKill).setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                            Log.d(TAG, "killing process: " + v.getTag());
                            activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses((String) v
                                    .getTag());
                            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                                    "plm.thesis.taskkiller.REFRESH_RECEIVER"));

                        }
                    });

            return view;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a multi-selectable ListView or a ListView with checkboxes - build your list to kill then kill them in a loop?

Comment: I guess this problem is not related to 'java-ee', but to 'java' and 'android'. I would recommend to set correct tags. Otherwise it is hard to find and answer.

Comment: ah sir i have a listview with checkboxes and a button also to kill the app. i did not post it because its to long.. ahahaha.. anyway that is one of my alternative. i want to use a for-loop but like i said i'am a newbie here in android. i didnt know where to start and put it in my code.. can you please help me with this? thank you so much! :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create onButton click on your kill button. Gather all selected buttons from your ListView with their position index then get the service names using these IDs and kill them. Guess it's easy as it is. I don't want to be a captain obvious though :)

I don't think you entirely understand how the stuff works in there so I had to ajust
your code quite abit I removed the BroadcastReceiver not to lose time you can play with 
it later.

Add to your AndroidManifest following line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
```

### and the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TaskKillerActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "TaskKillerActivity";
    TaskListAdapter adapter;
    ListView lv;
 //   RefreshReceiver receiver;
//
//    class RefreshReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
//        private static final String TAG = "RefreshReceiver";
//
//        @Override
//        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//            Log.d(TAG, "refreshing");
//            clearRunningProcessesList();
//            loadRunningProcesses();
//
//        }
//
//    }

    public void clearRunningProcessesList() {
        adapter.clearTasks();
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
       // adapter = new TaskListAdapter(this);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        ll.setLayoutParams(lp1);
        ll.setOrientation(1);
         lv = new ListView(this);
        adapter = new TaskListAdapter(this);
        loadRunningProcesses();

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        Button btnKill = new Button(this);
        btnKill.setText("kill task");

        btnKill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //listItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                for(TaskObject to :getTasksToKill())
                {
                   activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(to.getProcessName());

                }
           adapter.clearTasks();
           loadRunningProcesses();
           lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        ll.addView(btnKill);
        ll.addView(lv);
        setContentView(ll);


    }

    private List<TaskObject> getTasksToKill()
    {
        List<TaskObject> tol = new ArrayList<TaskObject>();

        for(int i =0;i<adapter.getCount();i++)
        {
            //RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)lv.getChildAt(i);

            TaskObject to = adapter.getItem(i);
            //CheckBox  cb = (CheckBox)rl.getChildAt(0);
            if(to.isToKill())
            {
                tol.add(to);
            }
        }

        return tol;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
       // getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    public void loadRunningProcesses() {

        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appinfolist = activityManager
                .getRunningAppProcesses();

        Log.d(TAG, "AppInfoList Size: " + appinfolist.size());

        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : appinfolist) {
            TaskObject runningtask = new TaskObject();
            runningtask.setPid(runningAppProcessInfo.pid);
            runningtask.setProcessName(runningAppProcessInfo.processName);
            adapter.addTask(runningtask);
        }
    }

    class TaskObject {
        private int pid;
        private String processName;
        private boolean toKill;

        public int getPid() {
            return pid;
        }

        public void setPid(int pid) {
            this.pid = pid;
        }

        public String getProcessName() {
            return processName;
        }

        public void setProcessName(String processName) {
            this.processName = processName;
        }

        public boolean isToKill() {
            return toKill;
        }

        public void setToKill(boolean toKill) {
            this.toKill = toKill;
        }
    }

    class TaskListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static final String TAG = "TaskListAdapter";

        ArrayList<TaskObject> list;
        Context context;

        public TaskListAdapter(Context context) {
            Log.d(TAG, "created new task list adapter");
            this.context = context;
            if (list == null) {
                list = new ArrayList<TaskKillerActivity.TaskObject>();
            }
        }

        public void addTask(TaskObject taskObject) {
            list.add(taskObject);
        }

        public void clearTasks() {
            list.clear();
            Log.d(TAG, "list size:" + list.size());
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public TaskObject getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           // LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
           // View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taskitem, null);
            RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
            TextView textPid = new TextView(context);
            textPid.setId(222222);
            textPid.setText(Integer.toString(getItem(position).getPid()));

            TextView textName = new TextView(context);
            textName.setId(333333);
            textName.setText(getItem(position).getProcessName());

            CheckBox chckKill = new CheckBox(context);
            chckKill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {
                //is chkIos checked?
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            getItem(position).setToKill(true);
        }

      }
    });


            chckKill.setTag(getItem(position).getPid());
            chckKill.setId(11111111);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

             rl.addView(chckKill,lp2);


            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, chckKill.getId());
            lp.setMargins(25,0,0,0);
            rl.addView(textName,lp);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, chckKill.getId());
            lp1.setMargins(25,20,0,0);
            rl.addView(textPid,lp1);


            return rl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: hahahaha .. but sir honestly want i want is a code for this. haha .. can you please help me? telling you the truth my code is from the net so i dont know how to do your recommendation. sir pleassssseeee !!

Comment: i dont know how will i thank you for your help sir sergey benner. :)) but THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH sir. now i can go on with my thesis. can i ask another question to you sir if i have a question again? cause you know i didn't know android like i said. sorry for the disturbance sir. :) i will now try this code sir ..

Comment: hi sir i have a problem, why is it that when i select and kill the app that i selected it does not remove in a list, at the same time the list is not updated every time i kill an application. because in my previous project it can remove it and update it. what will i do sir? hehe. is it because of some parts that you remove? am i right sir? THANK YOU AGAIN FOR YOUR REPLY SIR. i need you..

Comment: I've updated the code to update the list. Mark the question answered if it suits you please.

Comment: SIR! your code is very very great it works. THANK YOU SO MUCH sir... i owe you. i don't know how will i thank you for this sir .. i don't know how i feel today sir. but im very very happy because i can now proceed with my no.2 and no.3 problem in my thesis. can i ask for your help again if i have a question? because my no.2 problem is a little bit harder than no.1 i think, for me. hehe. THANKS AGAIN SIR :))

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted and ask another question the community will help you too. have fun.

Comment: sir Sergey Benner? can i ask question to you?