# How to use internal layouts in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing application which uses ListView. A ListView has items which contains 2 text fields and 1 picture. I have developed application with internal layouts for ListView items (android.R.layout. ...), but I don't know anything about layouts with image fields. Is there anything similar my task? Or should I make my own adapter for it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes, you should use your own adapter.

Answer (score 0):

in your class that implements ListAdapter you can make it:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_model_fipe, null);
    }
    ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgid);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your Adapter and override the getView(...) method there to return your View in your case it would a RelativeLayout holding within an ImageView+TextView+TextView 
to align them you can use the

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF(LEFT_OF,BELOW), yourView.getId());
```

I wrote an example application in some of my previous answers you can use the Adapter as a template for your own. The answer contains a code [how can i select and kill multiple application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851829/how-can-i-select-and-kill-multiple-application)

have fun