# Converting a Simple Listview program into an XML parser to the Listview

Tags: android, xml, listview, adapter

I am in the middle of converting a listview example into a program that operates by reading an xml file and then populate a list view with its contents. I seem to have hit a snag though. I'm not sure what to do with the Adapter I made for the first example and how to use it in this new program, any pointers would be appreciated.
Heres the main

```
Phonebook phonebook = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    list.setClickable(true);

    final List<Phonebook> listOfPhonebook = new ArrayList<Phonebook>();
    PhonebookAdapterView adapter = new PhonebookAdapterView(this, listOfPhonebook);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    try {

        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
         InputSource is = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.example));

        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(is.getByteStream()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Parsing Exception = " + e);
    }


    phonebook = MyXMLHandler.phonebook;
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Heres the xml handler

```
    Boolean currentElement = false;
    String currentValue = null;
    public static Phonebook phonebook = null;

    public static Phonebook getPhonebook() {
        return phonebook;
    }

    public static void setPhonebook(Phonebook p) {
        MyXMLHandler.phonebook = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        currentElement = true;

        if (localName.equals("maintag"))
        {
            /** Start */
            phonebook = new Phonebook();
        }
    }

    /** Called when tag closing ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name>
     * -- </name> )*/
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        currentElement = false;

        /** set value */
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
            phonebook.setName(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("phone"))
            phonebook.setPhone(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mail"))
            phonebook.setMail(currentValue);

    }

    /** Called to get tag characters ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name>
     * -- to get AndroidPeople Character ) */
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

        if (currentElement) {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentElement = false;
        }

    }

}
```

And the adapter view, which is the same back when it was a simple listview file. Im not sure how to factor in xml though.

public class PhonebookAdapterView extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private List<Phonebook> phonebook;

 public PhonebookAdapterView(Context theContext, List<Phonebook> theListPhonebook) {
        context = theContext;
        phonebook = theListPhonebook;
    }


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return phonebook.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return phonebook.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
     Phonebook entry = phonebook.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_row, null);
        }
        TextView tvContact = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContact);
        tvContact.setText(entry.getName());

        TextView tvPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMobile);
        tvPhone.setText(entry.getPhone());

        TextView tvMail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMail);
        tvMail.setText(entry.getMail());

      return convertView;
}
```

}

EDIT

MyXMLHAndler

public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

```
    Boolean currentElement = false;
    String currentValue = null;
    public static List<Phonebook> phonebook = new ArrayList<Phonebook>();

    public static List<Phonebook> getPhonebook() {
        return phonebook;
    }

    public static void setPhonebook(List<Phonebook> p) {
        MyXMLHandler.phonebook = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        currentElement = true;

        if (localName.equals("maintag"))
        {
            /** Start */
            phonebook = new ArrayList<Phonebook>();
        }
    }

    /** Called when tag closing ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name>
     * -- </name> )*/
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        currentElement = false;

        /** set value */
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
            ((Phonebook) phonebook).setName(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("phone"))
            ((Phonebook) phonebook).setPhone(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mail"))
            ((Phonebook) phonebook).setMail(currentValue);

    }

    /** Called to get tag characters ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name>
     * -- to get AndroidPeople Character ) */
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

        if (currentElement) {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentElement = false;
        }

    }

}
```

Second Edit

```
public List<Phonebook> phonebook = new ArrayList<Phonebook>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    list.setClickable(true);

    final List<Phonebook> listOfPhonebook = MyXMLHandler.getPhonebook();
    PhonebookAdapterView adapter = new PhonebookAdapterView(this, listOfPhonebook);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    try {

        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
         InputSource is = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.example));

        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(is.getByteStream()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Parsing Exception = " + e);
    }
```

XMLHandler

```
    public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    Boolean currentElement = false;
    String currentValue = null;
    public  List<Phonebook> phonebook = new ArrayList<Phonebook>();

    public List<Phonebook> getPhonebook() {
        return phonebook;
    }

    public void setPhonebook(List<Phonebook> p) {
        phonebook = p;
    }

    int entryCount;

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        currentElement = true;

        if (localName.equals("maintag"))
        {
            /** Start */
            Phonebook pb = new Phonebook();
            getPhonebook().add(pb);
            entryCount++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
  /** set value */
         if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
                ((Phonebook)phonebook.get(entryCount)).setName(currentValue);
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("phone"))
                ((Phonebook)phonebook.get(entryCount)).setPhone(currentValue);
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mail"))
                ((Phonebook)phonebook.get(entryCount)).setMail(currentValue);
}


    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

        if (currentElement) {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentElement = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're quite a few things to do to make it work.

First of all you will have to create your phonebook list by reading an XML file 
and putting a data into a List of the MyXMLHandler class
your

```
public static Phonebook phonebook = null;
```

should be

```
public static List<Phonebook> phonebook = new ArrayList<Phonebook>();
```

and populated accordingly within your XMLHandler class 
and after that you set this list into your adapter -

```
MyAdapter.setList(phonebook); // your method inside adapter
```

Then you're using the Phonebook objects from this list 
within your `getView()` class to populate your TextViews and `addView(TextView)` them
into your ConvertView object and return it.

I've made an example list application in this post [how can i select and kill multiple application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851829/how-can-i-select-and-kill-multiple-application)
or there's a bunch of posts  on how to create a listview.

UPDATED:

in your XMLHandler class
 Remove the statics from phonebook `public static List<Phonebook> phonebook` as well 
as from the set/getPhonebook() methods
you are NEWing the class and use the `myXMLHandler.getPhonebook();` in your activity class.

assuming you have the following xml

```
<phonebook>
<entry>
<name>abc</name>
<phone>def</phone>
<mail>ghi</mail>
</entry>
<entry>
<name>abc1</name>
<phone>def2</phone>
<mail>ghi3</mail>
</entry>
</phonebook>
```

### Working code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListActivity extends Activity {


    ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        ll.setLayoutParams(lp1);
        ll.setOrientation(1);
        lv = new ListView(this);
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = readXML();

        List<Phonebook> listOfPhonebook = myXMLHandler.getPhonebook();
        //adapter = new TaskListAdapter(this);
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, listOfPhonebook);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        ll.addView(lv);

        setContentView(ll);

    }

    private MyXMLHandler readXML() {
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = null;
        try {

            /** Handling XML */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
            InputSource is = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.a));

            /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
            myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(is.getByteStream()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Parsing Exception = " + e);
        }
        return myXMLHandler;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static final String TAG = "TaskListAdapter";


        List<Phonebook> phonebook;
        Context context;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<Phonebook> phonebook) {
            this.phonebook = phonebook;
            Log.d(TAG, "created new task list adapter");
            this.context = context;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return phonebook.size();
        }

        public Phonebook getItem(int position) {
            return phonebook.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
            TextView textPid = new TextView(context);
            textPid.setId(222222);
            textPid.setText(getItem(position).getName());

            TextView textName = new TextView(context);
            textName.setId(333333);
            textName.setText(getItem(position).getEmail());


            TextView textEmail = new TextView(context);
            textEmail.setId(444444);
            textEmail.setText(getItem(position).getEmail());

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            lp.setMargins(1, 0, 0, 0);
            rl.addView(textName, lp);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textName.getId());
            lp1.setMargins(1, 0, 0, 0);
            rl.addView(textPid, lp1);


            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textPid.getId());
            lp2.setMargins(1, 0, 0, 0);
            rl.addView(textEmail, lp2);


            return rl;
        }

    }

    class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        Boolean currentElement = false;
        String currentValue = null;
        public List<Phonebook> phonebook = new ArrayList<Phonebook>();
        int entryCount = 0;

        public List<Phonebook> getPhonebook() {
            return phonebook;
        }

        public void setPhonebook(List<Phonebook> p) {
            phonebook = p;
        }


        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

            currentElement = true;

            if (localName.equals("entry")) {
                /** Start */
                Phonebook pb = new Phonebook();
                getPhonebook().add(pb);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                throws SAXException {
            /** set value */
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
                (phonebook.get(entryCount)).setName(currentValue);
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("phone"))
                (phonebook.get(entryCount)).setPhone(currentValue);
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("mail"))
                (phonebook.get(entryCount)).setEmail(currentValue);

            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) entryCount++;
        }


        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {

            if (currentElement) {
                currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
                currentElement = false;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the reply, im a bit new to adapters and parsing xml in android. 2 Questions. In the xml handler, im having some trouble changing everything now that theres an arraylist of phonebooks, as in im not sure if Im right or not in my changes. Edit above

Comment: odd, I've made the changes but im now getting a blank listview.

Comment: are you sure that your XMLHandler reading the values into the object and the object is being set correctly into the local ArrayList?

Comment: please update the sources correspondingly so that I could see the changes you've done.

Comment: seem to be getting error on MyXMLHandler.getphonebook "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getPhonebook()"

Comment: I have updated the code check it your main activity should look like that you should have first instantiated the myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler(); as it is done there and only then call the getPhonebook() method

Comment: Thanks that did it, but the row in the list only displays the name field of the phonebook object, not the other two. I suspect the problem may be in my custom adapter but I dont see anything off about it.

Comment: you should check your Adapters getView() and how you add TextViews there and their layouts. This is most likely the problem. The correct layout within a holder view.

Comment: the Adapter view is the same as it was at the start of this question except i declared the textviews at the top then assigned them values in the getView but still no difference, its only reading the first value and only that. i took out the name value just to be sure and the row was created in the listview but no content.

Comment: Sigh. Well to avoid any further debates I've just made the working application and lets get over with it.

Comment: it looks like i left out the incrementing of the entrycount. Im really sorry for wasting your time and thank you very much.