# Reaching all entries of ListView

Tags: android

I'm using ListView to show all records from the database. Each row of the list has an additional checkbox. I want to make a button that when pressed will delete all checked records. However, when I'm iterating through the list and trying to get the reference to the rows with getChildAt(index), I can reach only 3 initial entries because the rest of them are hidden and in the application I have to use scrollbar for them.

How can I reach them that something like that worked fine:

```
for( int i = 0; i < taskList.size(); i++ ){
   View row = list.getChildAt(i);
   CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)
}
```

Comment: Is this a listView with a custom adapter? Please post the code where you populate the listView.

Comment: Here I've done the example awhile ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851829/how-can-i-select-and-kill-multiple-application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/how-to-use-radiogroup-in-listview-custom-adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the views, have the data that's backing the adapter have a field/variable in it that keeps track of the checked state. then, simply iterate through your collection and remove all of the ones that are checked. then notifydatasetchanged